# How to delete cell based of value in adjacent cell

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I need to delete a row if the adjacent cell is larger than the selected one. Essentially, if a cell in J is larger then the adjacent cell in K, I want the row to be deleted. So if J100 > K100, all data in row 100 should be deleted.I am currently able to do it with stationary value, so if J100 > 0 but not with a constantly shifting one.
for stationary values, I've got:

```
    Sub Delete_Row_Based_On_Bigger_Smaller_Value()

Dim ws As Worksheet

  ' Dont this bit, unless editted on a differently named sheet in which case replace sheet name with relevant sheet
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Set")
  ws.Activate

  ' Apply Filter. Edit the "ws.Range" with the letter you want to filter. Edit Criterial with what you want to delete. Dont touch the AutoFilter
  ws.Range("Q2:Q143691").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<400000"
  
  ' Delete Rows. Edit the "ws.Range" to be consistant with the above. Dont touch anything else
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ws.Range("Q2:Q143691").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  
  ' Clearing Filter. Dont touch this
  On Error Resume Next
    ws.ShowAllData
  On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: Bit confused as your explanation states you want to delete all row where adjacent cell value is less than current cell value but yet your code applies a filter and then deletes all visible cells? I would suggest, have a holding column where you can add this formula: `=IF($J100 > $K100, True, False)`. You can then have a UDF to delete all rows where the value is **True**

Comment: Thank you! Yeah my codes a smidge messy, it was mostly for the previous requirement of deleting any rows with a value of "0" or "<40k", rather than a constantly changing one. I'll try implementing your suggestion now! Thank you again :)

Comment: No problem. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Say we start with:

[image]

We examine each row starting at the bottom and work upwards:

```
Sub RowKiller()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long
    
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = N To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "J").Value > Cells(i, "K").Value Then
            Cells(i, "J").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

To get:

[image]

You should be able to adapt this approach to your coding.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using an adapted version of Zac's answer above, but this is super helpful and will definitely be using this in the future :)